# ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When i try to migrations of my django app model by writing :

python manage.py makemigrations

Then raises ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Here is my project screenshots :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4HQ6.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoM2m.jpg

Here is my model.py

```
from django.db import models
from ..krisi_user.models import krisi_user
#from src.krisi_user.models import krisi_user
# Creating krisi_user_image Model

class problem_image(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    krisi_user = models.ForeignKey(krisi_user,on_delete= models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

Comment: why are you trying to go up 2 levels to import something from another app? You should just do `from krisi_user.models import krisi_user`

Comment: btw, the convention is that model names begin with an Uppercase letter

Comment: It also showing error ..
see screenshot
https://imgur.com/Vq11Gmi

Comment: that screenshot doesn't actually show an error - it's just a linter warning about something, that might not necessarily be an error. (Depends how your linter is set up.) Do you actually get an error when running makemigrations - and if so, what is it?

Comment: oho i see .. but  i m using python .. I think in pycharm  no need to configure linter .